# Переключение языка на Manjaro Linux

Tags: linux, archlinux, fedora, manjaro

Я совсем недавно решил перейти с Винды на линукс. Данный момент заметил в Федоре. Теперь столкнулся с ним в Манджаро. Когда перевожу раскладку горячими клавишами и на фоне работает какое то приложение в режиме поверх всех окон (Например видео-плеер или окно ютуба), фокус переводится на это окно, а ни остается в том окне в котором я работал. Будь то мессенджер или редактор кода. И это крайне не удобно. Как это можно исправить? Помогите советом. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration#Switching_between_keyboard_layouts

Comment: какое окружение используется? вопрос нужно задавать применительно к рабочему окружению (DE/WM)